# Missing Push Notification Entitlement: While Resigining ipa

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, appstore-approval

Team,

We are releasing new update to our project, In the last version we dont have Push Notifications now are implementing all the process.

We work for a client where we used to send ipa file with our distribution profile (Push notifications are working for the ipa we are sending).

Once we send the working ipa, they will resign the ipa with there Distribution Profiles and Upload to appstore.

We have checked all the scenarios like, App Id enabled with Push Notification,SSl generated for Distribution (Is it mandatory for developing for developer also?).

The Resigning is successfull and we are able to upload the app to App Store.

But still we are getting the Below mail from Apple. Please Suggest what is the Solution for it

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for
>   Apple's Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement
>   is missing from the app's signature. To resolve this, make sure your
>   App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal.
>   Then, sign your app with a distribution provisioning profile that
>   includes the aps-environment entitlement. This will create the correct
>   signature, and you can resubmit your app. See "Provisioning and
>   Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for
>   more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification
>   service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future
>   submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework,
>   you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the
>   API.

Comment: Have you made sure to enable Push notifications in xCode > Project > Target > Capabilities > Push Notification? Also make sure you downloaded a new provisioning profile after you have enabled APNS for your app id, and make sure you install it by double clicking the downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

- You have to check if you have enabled push notifications in member
  center for the provisioning profile that you are using
- You have to check if you have enabled push notifications in xcode
  capabilities

i.e

just check *Entitlements.plist* for the following key values

```
 <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
```